# Error running mvn:generate to generate NEW project

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Given an archetype cmd -

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=io.confluent.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=kafka-connect-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=0.10.0.0
```

When I run this in a new, empty directory, it should create a source code folder structure for me.

Instead, I get the following -

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.113 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-05T14:37:19+13:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\Dev\sandpit\connect-quickstart). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

It appears to me that it's looking for a pom file, which I won't have, because this is a new project.

Any clues? Any help?

Environment: Windows. java -v == OpenJDK version "11.0.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=io.confluent.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=kafka-connect-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=0.10.0.0
```

runs all right on my computer. If I include the backslash, though, (which is present in your question), I get an error like the one you showed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=io.confluent.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=kafka-connect-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=0.10.0.0
```

you need to delete archetypes from io.confluent.maven.archetypes because there is not any groupId like it. worked on my computer

you can reference here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent.maven/kafka-connect-quickstart/0.10.0.0